# vertical carousel in android without using renderscript

Tags: android

I have got some example of horizontal but with renderscript, i want to run it in android 2.2 hence can't use renderscript.

So, Please help, how to make a vertical carousal or how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got it,needed a lot of hard work and patience but at last my vertical carousal is ready and to  without any render script.

I have done it by using [coverflow](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html) it is horizontal but can be made vertical, it need changes in certain methods in sort change all right to bottom and left to top, but it need huge patience. It's a very good code and one can easily understand how to use it.

Thanks. enjoy..